# How to Joins an Azure virtual machine into an AD Domain using Azure CLI

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-cli

I an using this github repo in order to join an Virtual Machine to an existing Azure Active Directory Domain :

> https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/201-vm-domain-join-existing

My attempt is to use it in a fully automated way with azure CLI

I have used this bash command line so far:

> az group deployment create --resource-group sql-rg --name slq-vm
>   --template-uri https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/master/201-vm-domain-join-existing/azuredeploy.json
>   --parameters '{ "vmList": "sql-vm", "location":"uksouth", "domainJoinUserName":"aduser@mydomain.uk",
>   "domainJoinUserPassword":"*****", "domainFQDN":"myfqdn" }'

After executing this command I do get this error:

> Azure Error: InvalidRequestContent Message: The request content was
>   invalid and could not be deserialized: 'Error converting value
>   "sql-vm" to type
>   'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ResourceStack.Frontdoor.Data.Definitions.DeploymentParameterDefinition'.
>   Path 'properties.parameters.vmList', line 1, position 196.'.

What is the right way to set parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for saving time for others:

```
--parameters '{ "vmList": {"value":"sql-vm"}, "domainJoinUserName": {"value":"aduser@mydomain.uk"}, "domainJoinUserPassword":{"value":"*****"}, "domainFQDN":{"value":"myfqdn"} }'
```

the parameter should be specified in the proper way.